# LocalStorage with access/refresh tokens spotify api

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, spotify, access-token

Currently I'm storing my refresh tokens and my access tokens in `localStorage`. When I clear the `localStorage` and cache I'm going to get errors from the Spotify api as the tokens are gone and the api can't be accessed any longer. How do approach this issue? Do away with `localStorage`? If so, how?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Phases from './components/Phases';
import About from './components/About';
import $ from 'jquery'
import { 
    BrowserRouter as Router, 
    Route, 
} from 'react-router-dom'; 

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    if (window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty('accessToken') === false){
      const params = this.getHashParams(); //tokens saved here
      const token = params.access_token;
      window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', token);
    }
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken') ? true : false,
    };          
  }

    componentDidMount(){
      const params = this.getHashParams(); //tokens saved here
      let refresh_token = "";
      if (params.refresh_token){
        refresh_token = params.refresh_token;
        window.localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refresh_token);
      }
      else{
        refresh_token = window.localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
      }
        
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/refresh_token',
        data: {
          'refresh_token': refresh_token
        }
      }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.access_token){
          window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.access_token);
        }
      });         
    }

    getHashParams() { //takes tokens from url
      var hashParams = {};
      var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
          q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
      e = r.exec(q)
      while (e) {
         hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
         e = r.exec(q);
      }
      return hashParams;
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          {this.state.loggedIn
            ?<div className='App'>
              <Route exact path = '/home' component= {Home}/>
              <Route exact path= '/phases' component = {Phases}/>
              <Route exact path= '/about' component = {About}/>
            </div>
            :null
          }
        </Router>         
    ); 
  }
}    
export default App;
```

Comment: I haven't used the Spotify API so I'm not sure exactly how it works. But you can set an event listener to listen for changes in storage then call some logic to re-authorise with Spotify when this happens.

Comment: I posted the code, if you can give me some insight into that it would greatly be appreciated